# IIS hosting - Website asks for login prompt

Tags: iis, webserver, hosting, web-hosting

Hosted a web application on IIS but it is throwing user a login prompt.
I have tried all the settings IIS to disable IIS but this still persists on users machine. It allows login via my id and password only. Any idea?

Comment: Show your IIS settings (Windows authentication on?). "It allows login via my id and password only", then what ID/password? Your local Windows account credentials or domain credentials? Any other user credentials work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, You should have some kind of authentication enabled in IIS, You can check the method you have enabled in autnentication:

[image]
[image]

You can refer to this link for the difference between these different Authentication:[Understanding Various Types of Authentication in IIS](http://vasanti.org/blog/?p=330)